# CSS to put navigation with no padding

Tags: html, css

I would like to put the navigation bar and the coloured line to the top of the site without the white gap. However when I add the following code:

```
body {    
    padding: 0 !important;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto; 

}
```

It affects the padding on all the paragraphs and future items I add, and it is too close to the border.

How can I just put the navigation bar and line at the top and sides without a white gap?

***Reference Image:***
  [image]

### Current CSS

```
/* layouts */ 
p { 
    margin: 5px; 
    font-size: 16px; 
    color: #04231b; 
    padding: 5px; 
} 
#topline { 
    margin-top:0px; 
    height:10px; 
    background-color:#118B69; 
} 
body { 
    padding: 0 !important; 
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
} 
h2 { 
    margin: 5px; 
    color: #052a20; 
    padding: 5px; 
} 
#photos { 
    float: left; 
} 
#text { 
    float: left; 
}
#header { 
    margin-top: 0 auto; 
} 
#form { 
    padding: 10px; 
} 
/* navigation bar */ 
#navigation ul { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-color: #094736; 
    margin-top: 0; 
} 
li { 
    float: right; 
} 
li a { 
    display: block; 
    color: white; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 14px 16px; 
    text-decoration: none; 
} 
li a:hover { background-color: #118B69; }
```

Comment: So you mean you still want the white on the right / left?

Comment: That's probably an `ul` with its "native" margin. Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: I would like no white for the navigation bar, but only for the content below the logo.

Comment: '<body>
    <div id="topline"></div>
    <div id="navigation">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="terms.html">Terms</a></li>
    <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="clare.html">Clare</a></li>
    <li><a href="barossa.html">Barossa</a></li>
    <li><a href="malarenvale.html">Malaren Vale</a></li>
    <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div> 
    <div id="header"><h1><img src="pictures/logo.png" alt="Logo" style="width:128px;height:128px">SA Historic Tours</h1></div>
 <div id="content">'

Comment: Code should be edited into the question...not added as a comment

Comment: Add a container div inside the body with the padding that you want, and wrap all the elements inside it, except for the header

Comment: A quick solution would be to give your navigation `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`

Comment: @gaynorvader The quick solution in this case is not a good solution.  This is a problem with the markup.

Comment: Please also post the CSS for the relevant HTML... It is probable that the `#topline` or `#navigation` have some style that makes that gap. Also, to be sure, inspect the rendered HTML (with Chrome it's with the developer tools) to be sure the body trully has no padding/margin.

Comment: I don't know how to add the code in the original question, keep getting errors. Here is the CSS...

Comment: /* layouts */

p {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #04231b;
    padding: 5px;
        }
#topline {
 margin-top:0px;
 height:10px;
 background-color:#118B69;
}
/*
body {    
    padding: 0 !important;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    
}
*/


h2 {
    margin: 5px;
    color: #052a20;
    padding: 5px;
}

#photos {
    float: left;
}

#text {
    float: left;
   
    }

Comment: #header {
    margin-top: 0 auto;
}

#form {
    padding: 10px;
}
/* navigation bar */


#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #094736;
    margin-top: 0;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #118B69;
}

Comment: @JosephMarikle Agreed, that's why I didn't put it down as an answer. However, sometimes people cannot change the html for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` is rendered with a margin.

Please style it without the margin, like this:

```
#navigation ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Also you can control the margin of the `li`.

Comment: Whilst true, that's not actuallty the issue here.

Comment: There's a more fundamental issue with the OP's markup/styling.  OP needs a container that exists on the same sibling level as the header that he can apply the padding to.  This answer won't solve the issue at all because the padding currently exists on the body.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you want to place content padding on the body element.  The body element should not have any padding in your case because you want the header to be flush with the top and sides.  Here is an illustration of the problem:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
}

header {
  background: #C55;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header content and nav</header>
  <p>This is a paragraph of text</p>
  <p>here is another</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</body>
```

The main issue is that you have the content too high in your DOM.  the paragraphs are immediate children or close to immediate children, but they should have a container like so:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  /* padding: 1em; */
}

header {
  background: #C55;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header content and nav</header>
  <div class="container">
    <p>This is a paragraph of text</p>
    <p>here is another</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Notice that padding is removed off of the body and instead applied to the container.

Comment: But the OP explicitly set the body to have no padding nor margin, so, although your illustrations are correct, none fit the problem. My guess is that some other style is affecting the body padding. I would love to see the OPs code to determine that.

Comment: my CSS code is in the comments section, of 2 parts as I did not know how to add it to my question

Comment: Re-reading all the comments, maybe your problem is not an unwanted padding on the top, but rather a "wanted" padding on the content, and using the `body` styling was not what you wanted? in that case, follow @Joseph Marikle answer, if not, inspect the body to see if something else is styling it.

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like, no padding on top, and wanted for content

Comment: In that case, go for the container for the content, add the desired padding to it, remove the padding + margin on the body and accept @Joseph Marikle answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your two green divs to be displayed right at the top and extend to both sides of the window, you should remove the margin from them. Something like this:

```
#topline,
#navigation
{
    margin: 0 0 20px 0px;
}
```

However, it looks like your body has it's default margin too, in which case you will also need to remove this with:

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
```

it might then be worth putting all the elements further down in a wrapping div or section, which you can then give some margin of it's own.

It would also help if you could paste in your CSS.